# Threads in java, where 3 called methods run simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to have the 3 methods running at the same time so I can e.g. add 3 times in a row, or subtract and check whenever I want. How do I do this? So far my output is just the 3 methods one after another.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) { 
                    add();
                    remove();
                    check();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();      

    }

    static int total = 0;

    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    static synchronized int add() {
        System.out.println("How much was added?");
        int a = s.nextInt();
        total = total + a;
        return total;
    }

    static synchronized int remove() {
        System.out.println("How much was removed?");
        int b = s.nextInt();
        return total = total - b;
    }

    static synchronized void check() {
        System.out.println("Would you like to know how much is left?");
        String str = s.next();
        if (str.equals("Yes"))
            System.out.println(total);

    }

}
```

Comment: You just have one thread or expecting more and are you sure you want static method's?

Comment: "running at the same time" doesnt mean what you think it means ... What is your ACTUAL goal?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are confused of sorts - you dont need multiple threads at all, a simple command-interface is everything necessary to make your assignment work like you want it to behave :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;    


public class Calc {

    private final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Calc instance;
    private int current = 0;

    Calc()
    {       
        mainThread.start();
    }

    private final Thread mainThread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mainLoop();         
        }

    };

    private void mainLoop()
    {
        boolean end = false;
        while(!end)
        {
            System.out.println("what would you like to do?  [ \"A\" = ADD, \"R\" = REMOVE, \"C\" = CHECK, \"Q\" = QUIT ]");
            String command = scanner.next();
            switch(command.trim().toUpperCase())
            {
            case "A" : add(); break;
            case "R" : subtract(); break;
            case "C" : check(); break;
            case "Q" : 
            {
                System.out.println("exiting, last value was " + current); 
                end = true;
                break;
            }
            default : System.err.println("unknown command!"); break;
            }
        }       
    }

    private void add()
    {
        System.out.println("how much would you like to add?");
        int val = scanner.nextInt();
        current += val;
    }

    private void subtract()
    {
        System.out.println("how much would you like to subtract?");
        int val = scanner.nextInt();
        current -= val;
    }

    private void check()
    {
        System.out.println("current value : " + current);   
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        instance = new Calc();              
    }

}
```

All of this works because there is only one single instance, if there were to be more than 1 instance you would run into many problems - these are called "racing conditions".

My advice is : dont use threads if you're not a skilled expert, even the simplest of threads (with concurrent access to fields) need some sort of synchronization-object.

If you **really** want to start learning about threads always use [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)s, [CountdownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)es or something similar - and make them private static, of course.

This seems to be a good tutorial : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm